# Trouble with finding new line character from a string, Reading Text from .txt file

Tags: c#

I am reading text from a `.TXT` file in a `String`. I am using `File.ReadAllText`.

```
 string Str= File.ReadAllText(@"C:\temp\file.txt", Encoding.Default);
```

Let's assume the `Str` contains following string.

```
string Str= @"one
    two
    three";
```

Now the problem is I cannot find the newline characters from `Str`.

```
string[] lines = Str.Split('\n');

foreach(string line in lines)
{
  Console.WriteLine(line.IndexOf('\n'); // prints -1 three times
}
```

Is there any way I can find newline character in this situation? Please suggest.

Comment: You just split on `\n`. When you split on a character, that character is removed from the results. As an experiment, try looking at the results from `var split = "1,2,3".Split(',');`

Comment: You already removed the `\n` by calling `Split('\n')`. How do you expect `\n` to be still present? It sounds like you're expecting a bug in `Split` method?

Comment: If you want to do something with the lines, then why not use `File.ReadAllLines(String, Encoding)`?

Comment: If you really need to have the newlines preserved after the split (and I don't know why you would), you could use `Regex.Split` with a lookbehind like this: `string[] lines = new Regex("(?<=\n)").Split(Str)`;

Comment: Your latest edit has *completely* changed the question to the extent that the answer no longer make sense in context. Please don't do that. If you have a different question, please ask a new question.

Comment: @MattBurland I have gave the clarification in the Update as well. That why I changed the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.Split` will delete the delimiter characters, and the resulting output will not include them.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Delimiter characters are not included in the elements of the returned
>   array.

If you need to find the length of a line, just use the `.Length` property of the string.

In any case, as mentioned in the comments, use the [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx) method to avoid having to split the file contents yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Per [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) for the `String.Split` method:

> Delimiter characters are not included in the elements of the returned
>   array.

Just as an observation, if you are trying to load a file and process it line by line you may want to do something [like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(@"C:\temp\file.txt"))
{
   Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```